# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Authenticate against our own bearer server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin, asp.net-identity-2

All,

I've got a security server which sole purpose is to provide bearer tokens from a single endpoint: http://example.com/token

Example request:

```
POST http://example.com/token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: example.com
Content-Length: 73

grant_type=password&username=example@example.com&password=examplePassword
```

Example response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 16 Aug 2016 12:04:39 GMT
{
  "access_token": "xxxx",
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "expires_in": 17999,
  "refresh_token": "xxxx",
  ".issued": "Tue, 16 Aug 2016 12:04:38 GMT",
  ".expires": "Tue, 16 Aug 2016 17:04:38 GMT"
}
```

We have an angular application which uses this endpoint to authenticate, and does so just fine.

What we are trying to achieve without much success is to create an MVC application which uses the same server to authenticate, we'd like the code to sit on top of Identity 2.0 if possible.

In our `AccountController` (example project) we have our `Login(LoginModel model)` method which handles login and looks like this (same as example project template):

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

We have our own implemention of IUserStore, UserManager, SignInManager.

I've considered overriding

```
public Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout) on `SignInManager<,>` and make a web call across to the security server.
```

The default implementation of `PasswordSignInAsync` calls `UserManager.FindByNameAsync` however this would mean I'd have to expose a lookup method on my security server to confirm a username exists which really doesn't sound good.

I must be missing something and I know it wouldn't be this complicated, our MVC app needs to use cookie authentication but also maintain the bear token for subsequent calls to our other resource server.

(I appreciate I might be mixing up technologies here, hence the question).

This is also running on OWIN.

Comment: You want a new MVC application to use an existing Authentication Server for it's token? If so, what advantage do you hope to gain?

Comment: Your MVC application dont need to have a Login controller. Not one that take the user and password anyway. Your MVC application should authenticate and get a AccessToken from your SecurityServer, and you should decrypt this token on MVC. This will be possible if the server shares some properties. Read this article for some more information:
http://bitoftech.net/2014/09/24/decouple-owin-authorization-server-resource-server-oauth-2-0-web-api/

Comment: Not sure whether I got your question correct - *What we are trying to achieve without much success is to create an MVC application which uses the same server to authenticate* - Aint it possible to hit that security server token endpoint via HttpClient from your AccountController Login action with the username and password which would inturn set the token in the response cookie if the request is authenticated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I don't think you should use Identity 2.0 in your MVC application. You should create an `AuthenticationClient` to call your authentication server, you could also use this library to build such a client https://www.nuget.org/packages/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Client/

```
public class AuthenticationClient {
    public ClaimsIdentity GetClaimsIdentity(string username, string password) {
         //Call your authentication server to get your token and also claims associated with your identity.
         //You can look at an example code how to do it: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/Clients/ConsoleResourceOwnerClient/Program.cs
         //and create a ClaimsIdentity object out of those information

         var identity = GetIdentity();

         //The key point here is to add AccessToken and RefreshToken as custom claims to your identity so you retrieve these tokens back on subsequent requests.
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", accessToken));
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", refreshToken));
    }
}
```

This will fulfill your requirements:

> Use cookie authentication but also maintain the bear token for subsequent calls to our other resource server.

Your `Login` method on `AccountController` should be like this:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
     var identity = authenticationClient.GetClaimsIdentity(model.UserName, model.Password);

     if (identity == null) {
         return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
     }
     //Sign in the user
     var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
     var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
     authenticationManager.SignIn(identity);

     return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I assume that you already register this middleware to use Cookie authentication:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
   app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
   {
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
   });
}
```

Now for all subsequent requests, you could retrieve back the access token to call your resource server from your ClaimsIdentity:

```
User.Identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "access_token");
```